# Getting info phone directory connected by usb

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

I was looking into starter command prompt things and when I want to list my drives I use:

```
wmic LOGICALDISK get name
```

which outputs:

```
C:
D:
E:
F:
```

My C and D are hard drives, E is CD drive and F is phone but in this case its for phone installation for PC and setup files.

How can I get into portable devices as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVU16.png) for my phone storage?

I tried by typing device name like for other drivers but it says it can't find anything...

Comment: What about issuing `wmic logicaldisk` and see what other properties to use? Select the drivetype you want with i.e. `WMIC logicaldisk where "DriveType=2" list brief`

Comment: I tried WMIC logicaldisk where "DriveType=2" list brief but it says No instances available

Comment: You may redirect the output of `wmic logicaldisk|clip` and load the clipboard content into an editor to examine what your "F:" drivetype looks like.

Comment: Why my F I have 2 drives when I connect my phone here, one is F where is my phone driver installation for PC and other is portable device which is not visible as logicaldisk